# CodeFirst в EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Прошу помочь мне с таким не сложным вопросом. Для начала начну с того, как организована у меня работа с базой. Достаточно просто и по книжке.

Есть 2 Доменных класса - New и Comment

```
public class New
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NewID {get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    internal void SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int NewID { get; set; }

    internal void SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Есть репозиторий для работы с классом New

```
public class NewRepository : INewRepository
{
    private EFCFDatebase context = new EFCFDatebase();
    public IQueryable<New> News
    {
        get { return context.News; }
    }
}
```

Соответственно и класс базы данных

```
public class EFCFDatebase: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<New> News { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Вот контроллер где Я вытягиваю данные

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /News/
    public INewRepository repoNew;
    public NewsController(INewRepository _repoNew)
    {
        repoNew = _repoNew;
    }

    public ActionResult New(int NewId)
    {
        New vModel = new New();
        vModel = repoNew.News.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NewID == NewId);
        return View(vModel);
    }

}
```

А теперь вопрос. Если рассмотреть класс `New` в нём есть коллекция Comments. `Code-First` создаёт подчинённую структуру таблиц при первом обращении к базе.

http://clip2net.com/clip/m278744/1402646151-clip-8kb.png?nocache=1

И заполняет её данными из моего метода инициализатора .

```
public class DBInicializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFCFDatebase>
{
    protected override void Seed(EFCFDatebase context)
    {

      var News = new List<New> 
      { 
         new New { 
            Title = "My First Photo", 
            Body = "This is part of the sample data",
            Comments = new List<Comment> { new Comment { Author = "aaa", Body = "bbb bbb" } }
         }, 
         new New { 
            Title = "My Second Photo", 
            Body = "This is part of the sample data"
         } 
      };

        News.ForEach(s => context.News.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Тогда почему когда я вытягиваю данные из базы , мне возвращается объект New с коллекцией Comments равной null?

http://clip2net.com/clip/m278744/1402646252-clip-20kb.png?nocache=1

Разве code - first не должен автоматически её заполнять?

Comment: New vModel = new New(); // лишнее это`


        vModel = repoNew.News.FirstOrDefault(n => n.NewID == NewId);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина такого поведения EF заключается в том, что вы не указали тип загрузки связанных данных для свойства `Comments` класса `New`.

Чтобы коллекция не была пустой, можно добавить ключевое слово `virtual` свойству `Comments`, чтобы использовать `Lazy Loading`

```
public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

Возможен другой вариант: вызвать метод `Include`, чтобы использовать `Eager Loading`

```
vModel = repoNew.News.Include("Comments").FirstOrDefault(n => n.NewID == NewId);
```

Только для этого еще надо будет изменить тип возвращаемого значения у `News` в репозитории с `IQueryable<New>` на `DbSet<New>`.

Советую почитать [статью по теме](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).